# Create a region-specific IP address for testing

Tags: ip, cucumber, watir

For a project I am working on I need to fake an IP address to appear that I am coming from another country.

Basically if the IP detected is from the UK, show popup A, if the IP detected is from outside the UK then show popup B.

I would like to be able to automate this. Currently all our browser automation tests are written in cucumber/watir and I would like to get a solution that uses the same framework.

Does anyone know of a possible way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be possible if are on same network. But I am just guessing. Not sure about it.

Comment: its a legit question... there are often legal requirements to do different things for different countries.  when you write such code, how do you set up automated testing of it?

Comment: @Артём Царионов: It is legitimate (though misguided if used for content restrictions) for a website to want to detect where a visitor is from.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов - what does it pay to suggest that somebody is a criminal, due to them asking a question about spoofing an I.P.? Maybe he/she is actually trying to learn whether somebody can spoof an I.P. on his/her server and prefers to ask in this format as a means to elicit more responses. Hobgoblins like you ruin the free world.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for prompt replies. I have no intention of stealing anyones CC number! The project is to offer customers a localised experience - e.g - if IP is from Germany, offer to take them to .de site rather than .co.uk. A lot of websites do this, amazon, cnn to name a couple.

Comment: agreed, deleted comment, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, if you care about the result of your HTTP request getting back to you, IP spoofing is not possible.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing

If this is for *testing*, you can run a Virtual Machine on your local network for each use case "in UK" and "not in UK".  Assign a local IP address to each VM that will not change.

Run a HTTP proxy server in each VM and have your unit test connect through different proxy servers depending on the test case.

Add override logic to your geolocation code to consider these well-known, local IP addresses to be part of their respective test locations.  Note that a well-behaved proxy server will include both the proxy server's IP address and the original IP address in the request.  Be sure you use the proxy server's IP address for geolocation for this unit test (generally, you would want to use the original IP address where available for production geolocation).

Note that it is *very* easy for anyone who cares to circumvent this type of control.  It is possible to gain access to an HTTP proxy server in the UK that intentionally does not forward the original IP address for a very small fee.

Comment: Ok thanks Eric. I will talk this over with the devs at work and see if its possible to come up with a solution using VMs.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to add some magic request parameter which would allow you to switch between UK and others. For example, let's say something like this would enable "*UK mode*":

```
browser.goto "localhost/?country=UK"
```

Then, in server-side there should be some if-statement for checking that parameter. In pseudo-code:

```
if get_parameters["country"] == "UK"
  enable_uk_mode
end
```

That would allow you to just specify that `GET parameter` to switch ON "*UK mode*" or some other mode. I'm usually going this route, since installing and managing all VM-s and proxy servers and managing all their configuration is just taking much more time than the effort of adding some control logic to development mode of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how is made the detection, in some case, you should use the browser language. This kind of code :

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['intl.accept_languages'] = "fr"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

For the ip, why not consider to use a proxy ?

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new :http => 'my.proxy.com:8080', :ssl => 'my.proxy.com:8080'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

I think you should made the both : it will be more as a real user was using his browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "FakeIP" cookie which your HTTP request handler checks for, and if the application runs in test mode, then it overwrites the real IP with the fake IP.

Example: I'm actually doing this in my Play Framework / Scala app. In my HTTP request class:

```
def ip =
  if (!Play.isTest)
    underlyingRequest.remoteAddress
  else
    underlyingRequest.cookies.get("FakeIP").map(_.value).getOrElse(
                                      underlyingRequest.remoteAddress)
```

And then at the top of my Selenium E2E test:

```
add cookie ("FakeIP", "111.112.113.114")
```

There's not much more than this to it :-)    (at least in my case)

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for this question.
At the moment I'm testing redirection in drupal 9.
To test different regions like Europa/Africa/Azja/America it's possible to use BrowserStack Live just region using MacOs.
Same story with test automation.

[image]